# How to disable a job in oracle with dbms_scheduler

Tags: oracle, jobs, dbms-scheduler

I created a job which runs in my database successfully with DBMS_SCHEDULER ,but now I need to disable this job, how can i do this?
thanks!

Comment: How did you create the job?  Did you use `dbms_job`?  Or `dbms_scheduler`?

Comment: i have create on dbms_job

Answer (score 8):

Although the current answers provide a solution to how disable a job, I wanted to go a bit further and explain you how the job is created has an effect on whether the job needs to be disabled in the first place.

I am assuming you are using `dbms_scheduler`.

**Job is created with `auto_drop` true and `enabled` true**

In this case, once the job is created ( assuming you don't have any start time in the future ) the job executes immediately ( because it is enabled ) and then it is dropped automatically ( auto_drop is true )

```
SQL> begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
        (
                job_name             => 'MY_TEST',
                job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                job_action           => 'begin dbms_lock.sleep(5); end;',
                enabled              =>  TRUE ,
                auto_drop            =>  TRUE
        );
end;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exec  dbms_lock.sleep(5); -- waiting 5 seconds 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select job_name,job_action from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_TEST' ;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

**Job is created with `auto_drop` to false and `enabled` to true**

In this case, the job runs and it disables itself automatically. In this scenario you don't need to do anything to disable it.

```
SQL> begin
  2  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
  3     (
  4             job_name             => 'MY_TEST',
  5             job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  6             job_action           => 'begin dbms_lock.sleep(5); end;',
  7             enabled              =>  TRUE ,
  8             auto_drop            =>  FALSE
  9     );
 10* end;
 11  /

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select job_name , state, enabled from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_TEST' ;

JOB_NAME    STATE           ENABLE
----------------------------------
MY_TEST     SUCCEEDED       FALSE
```

Therefore, if your job is enabled is because it has a calendar frequency associated to it, so once has executed, it states enabled until the next time it has to execute

**Job with frequency**

It means that the job was created to executed based on an expression calendar. In this case, the job executes based on the calendar expression associated to it, and remains enabled and in state SCHEDULED.

```
SQL>  exec dbms_scheduler.drop_job ( job_name => 'MY_TEST' ) ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
(job_name             => 'MY_TEST',
 job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
 job_action           => 'begin dbms_lock.sleep(5); end;',
 enabled              =>  TRUE ,
 start_date           =>  systimestamp ,
 repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;'
 );
 end;
 / 

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select job_name , state, enabled from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_TEST' ;

JOB_NAME        STATE           ENABLE
--------------------------------------
MY_TEST       SCHEDULED         TRUE
```

In this case, as it was point out in the other answers:

```
SQL> exec dbms_scheduler.disable ( 'MY_TEST' ) ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select enabled  from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_TEST' ;
    
ENABL
-----
FALSE
```

**Summary**

- If you want to run a job just once and eliminate it, use the option 1 ( `auto_drop` and `enabled` )
- If you want to run a job and leave it there for run it on demand whenever you want, but disabled. Use option 2 ( `auto_drop` to false and `enabled` to true )
- Normally you disable jobs that are created with frequency and execute based on some kind of calendar expression.

Obviously, that is just a set of small examples of the many options you have available with `dbms_scheduler`

Answer (score 7):

Oracle has a good package for schedule jobs.

In your case , you need disable procedure.
Here is the detailed information about [dbms_scheduler](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)

Simply call this using oracle new query window like this and your job will be disabled:

```
begin dbms_scheduler.disable('job-name'); end;
```

Or in command window :

```
exec dbms_scheduler.disable('SCHEMA_MNTC_JOB');
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can create a PL/SQL Procedure that disable your job, with the name in parameter

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DISABLE('name_of_your_job');
END;
/
```

2. Execute it
   `EXEC dbms_scheduler.disable('name_of_your_job');`

I hope this will solve your problem